# Modify a json file with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

as I can modify a json in laravel file?
In the methods available for the File class, only allows me to add additional text:

```
File::append($path, $data);
```

however, can not find a method to modify.

**example:**

```
public function json(){
      $data = json_encode([
         'data1' => 'hello',
          'data2' => 'world' ]);
  File::append($path, $data);
}

public function ModifyJson(){

//how change value for data2?  

}
```

thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: file_get_contents(), then json_decode(), then modify, then file_put_contents()

Answer (score 3):

Use `$data = json_decode($your_file_content,true)`, then modify `$data` as normal php array, and before save use `json_encode($data)` and save data.